# VHDL -how to set range of values?

Tags: vhdl

I need to get pulse of 80nsec . in order to do this I use clock of 50Mhz and want to count 4 clock rising edges .((1/50M)*4=80nSec) . In order to do this I wrote this code :

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.std_logic_textio.ALL;
USE IEEE.std_logic_arith.ALL;
USE IEEE.numeric_bit.ALL;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;
USE IEEE.std_logic_signed.ALL;
USE IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.ALL;
USE IEEE.math_real.ALL;
USE IEEE.math_complex.ALL;

ENTITY one_pulse_80_nSec IS

    PORT(
        clk_in             : IN  std_logic;
        clr                : IN  std_logic;
        clk_out_one_signal : OUT std_logic
    );
END one_pulse_80_nSec;

ARCHITECTURE logic_one_pulse_80_nSec OF one_pulse_80_nSec IS
BEGIN
    --clock_divider 
    PROCESS(clk_in, clr)
        VARIABLE a : integer := 0;

    BEGIN
        IF (clk_in'event AND clk_in = '1') THEN

            a := a + 1;
            IF ((5 < a) & (a < 9)) THEN
                clk_out_one_signal <= '1';

                --                          else 
                clk_out_one_signal <= '0';

            END IF;

        END IF;

    END PROCESS;

END logic_one_pulse_80_nSec;
```

but I get this error : 
 can't determine definition of operator ""&""

where I am wrong ? I added all the libraries   ...

Comment: Why not consult documentation such as [this](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/operator.html)? There is no `&` operator in VHDL in the logical operation sense.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think the OP is thinking about how conditions work in C/C++ with the `&`. There is an `&` operator and it's for concatenation of elements and/or arrays. Not sure why the OP was able to do `and` but figured that `&` would provide the same function.

Comment: Use ' and '  instead of ' & '.

Comment: & is the concatenation operator. Your design only uses the first use clause. Using and instead of &, you'd get one pulse until the integer a rolled over. A very low repetition rate, but more than one pulse.

Answer (score 2):

if you had searched a little bit, you would have found a lot of explanations to your problems.

First, you do not need all of those library, use the standard ones which are IEEE.std_logic_1164 and IEEE.numeric_std. the others are specific to some problem (not your case) or are not official standard libraries of IEEE. (see this site for more information on the different libraries: https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/stdpkg.html)

You define a signal named `clr` but never use it.

Your indentations are horrible, which make your code very hard to read.

You should not use `clk_in'event and clk_in='1'` but prefer `rising_edge(clk_in)` (see this web site for more explanation : http://vhdlguru.blogspot.com/2010/04/difference-between-risingedgeclk-and.html)

I have no idea why you have commented `else` in your code.

You can also replace:

- `end logic_one_pulse_80_nSec;` by `end architecture;` without the name of the architecture, I believe it is more clear that way.
- `end one_pulse_80_nSec;` by `end entity;` without the name of the entity, I believe it is more clear that way.

Now your question: 
`&` is used for concatenation (array or element & array or element result array), what your are looking for is probably the logic `and`.

You corrected code:

```
library IEEE; 
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;


entity one_pulse_80_nSec is 
    port( 
        clk_in : in std_logic ;
        clr  : in std_logic;
        clk_out_one_signal: out std_logic
        );
end entity;


architecture logic_one_pulse_80_nSec of one_pulse_80_nSec is 
    begin 

    --clock_divider
    process(clk_in, clr)
        variable a : integer := 0;

    begin 
        if (rising_edge(clk_in)) then 

            a:=a+1;

            if((5<a) and (a<9)) then 
                clk_out_one_signal<='1';

            else 
                clk_out_one_signal<='0';

            end if;
        end if ;                

    end process;
end architecture;
```